vb.net ID must be set when sending emails using OAuth2
I have recently started getting an error message as soon as I try to send an e-mail. And I can't find the cause or a solution to the problem. And since I couldn't find anything on the Internet, I think I have an error somewhere, but I don't see it.
Here is the code I use to send e-mails via the Exchange online client:
Public Class MyEws
    Private _ClientSecret As String, _MailBoxAdress As String
    Private ReadOnly AppId As String = "1234-5841-1A242-aaaa-Test", TenantId As String = "Test-8544-321-Test-12dbcf"

    Public WriteOnly Property ClientSecret As String
        Set
            _ClientSecret = Value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property MailBoxAdress As String
        Get
            Return _MailBoxAdress
        End Get
        Set
            _MailBoxAdress = Value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Sub New(ClientSecret As String, MailBoxAdress As String)
        Me.ClientSecret = ClientSecret
        Me.MailBoxAdress = MailBoxAdress
    End Sub

    Public Sub New(ClientSecret As String)
        Me.ClientSecret = ClientSecret
    End Sub

    Public Function CreateAuthenticateExchangeService() As ExchangeService
        Dim Ccab As IConfidentialClientApplication
        Dim EwsScopes = {"https://outlook.office365.com/.default"}
        Dim Result As AuthenticationResult, EwsClient As ExchangeService
        Dim ClientOptions As New ConfidentialClientApplicationOptions With {.ClientId = Me.AppId, .ClientSecret = _ClientSecret, .TenantId = Me.TenantId}
        Try
            Ccab = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.CreateWithApplicationOptions(ClientOptions).Build()
            Dim t = Ccab.AcquireTokenForClient(EwsScopes).ExecuteAsync
            t.Wait()
            Result = t.Result
            EwsClient = New ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2013_SP1) With {
            .Url = New Uri("https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx"),
            .Credentials = New OAuthCredentials(Result.AccessToken),
            .ImpersonatedUserId = New ImpersonatedUserId(ConnectingIdType.SmtpAddress, MailBoxAdress)}
            Return EwsClient
        Catch ex As Exception
            Dim t = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, Date.Now.ToString("F", ciDE), "Folgender Fehler ist im EwsExportMailAttachment - OAuth2 aufgetreten:", "Fehlernummer: " & ex.HResult, "Fehlerbeschreibung: " & ex.Message, "Stacktrace: " & ex.StackTrace)
            Dim t2 As New MyFile(Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "Log.txt"))
            t2.Write(t, True)
            Return Nothing
        End Try
    End Function
    
Public Sub SendMail(Mail As MimeMessage)
        MailSend(Mail, Nothing)
End Sub

Public Sub SendMail(Mail As MimeMessage, Attachment As MyFile)
        Dim MyAttachments As New List(Of MyFile) From {Attachment}
        MailSend(Mail, MyAttachments)
End Sub

    Public Sub SendMail(Mail As MimeMessage, Attachment As List(Of MyFile))
        MailSend(Mail, Attachment)
    End Sub
    Private Sub MailSend(Mail As MimeMessage, Attachments As List(Of MyFile))
        Dim Ews = CreateAuthenticateExchangeService()
        Dim Message = New EmailMessage(Ews)
        With Message
            .Sender = New EmailAddress(Mail.Sender.Name, Mail.Sender.Address)
            .From = .Sender
            .Subject = Mail.Subject
            Dim Recipients = Mail.GetRecipients(True)
            For i = 0 To Recipients.Count - 1
                Dim Receiver = Recipients(i)
                .ToRecipients.Add(New EmailAddress(Receiver.Name, Receiver.Address))
            Next
            If Mail.Cc IsNot Nothing Then
                For i = 0 To Mail.Cc.Count - 1
                    Dim CC = DirectCast(Mail.Cc(i), MailboxAddress)
                    .CcRecipients.Add(New EmailAddress(CC.Name, CC.Address))
                Next
            End If
            If Mail.Bcc IsNot Nothing Then
                For i = 0 To Mail.Bcc.Count - 1
                    Dim BCC = DirectCast(Mail.Bcc(i), MailboxAddress)
                    .BccRecipients.Add(New EmailAddress(BCC.Name, BCC.Address))
                Next
            End If
            If Mail.Body.ContentType.MimeType = "text/html" Then
                .Body = New MessageBody(BodyType.HTML, Mail.GetTextBody(Text.TextFormat.Html))
            Else
                .Body = New MessageBody(BodyType.Text, If(Mail.GetTextBody(Text.TextFormat.Plain), String.Empty))
            End If
            If Attachments IsNot Nothing Then
                For i = 0 To Attachments.Count - 1
                    .Attachments.AddFileAttachment(Attachments(i).FileName & Attachments(i).Extension, Attachments(i).FullPath)
                Next
            End If
        End With
        Message.SendAndSaveCopy()
    End Sub
End Class

Hier noch die Fehlermeldung inkl. Stacktrace
System.ArgumentException
  HResult=0x80070057
  Nachricht = The Id property must be set.
  Quelle = Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices
  Stapelüberwachung:
   bei Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ImpersonatedUserId.WriteToXml(EwsServiceXmlWriter writer)
   bei Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceRequestBase.WriteToXml(EwsServiceXmlWriter writer)
   bei Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceRequestBase.EmitRequest(IEwsHttpWebRequest request)
   bei Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceRequestBase.BuildEwsHttpWebRequest()
   bei Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceRequestBase.ValidateAndEmitRequest(IEwsHttpWebRequest& request)
   bei Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.MultiResponseServiceRequest`1.Execute()
   bei Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeService.InternalCreateItems(IEnumerable`1 items, FolderId parentFolderId, Nullable`1 messageDisposition, Nullable`1 sendInvitationsMode, ServiceErrorHandling errorHandling)
   bei Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.Item.InternalCreate(FolderId parentFolderId, Nullable`1 messageDisposition, Nullable`1 sendInvitationsMode)
   bei Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.EmailMessage.InternalSend(FolderId parentFolderId, MessageDisposition messageDisposition)
   bei Test.MyEws.MailSend(MimeMessage Mail, List`1 Attachments) in C:\Users\maurice.rothmann\source\repos\Test\MailCl.vb: Zeile254
   bei Test.MyEws.SendMail(MimeMessage Mail) in C:\Users\maurice.rothmann\source\repos\Test\MailCl.vb: Zeile210
   bei Test.Form2.KryptonButton1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\maurice.rothmann\source\repos\Test\Form2.vb: Zeile35
   bei System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   bei Krypton.Toolkit.KryptonButton.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   bei Krypton.Toolkit.KryptonButton.OnButtonClick(Object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
   bei Krypton.Toolkit.ButtonController.MouseUp(Control c, Point pt, MouseButtons button)
   bei Krypton.Toolkit.ViewManager.MouseUp(MouseEventArgs e, Point rawPt)
   bei Krypton.Toolkit.VisualControlBase.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs e)
   bei System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
   bei System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   bei Krypton.Toolkit.VisualControlBase.WndProc(Message& m)
   bei System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
   bei System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
   bei System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
   bei System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   bei System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   bei System.Windows.Forms.Form.ShowDialog(IWin32Window owner)
   bei Test.Form1.Button3_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\maurice.rothmann\source\repos\Test\Form1.vb: Zeile9
   bei System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   bei System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
   bei System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
   bei System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   bei System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
   bei System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
   bei System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
   bei System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
   bei System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
   bei System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   bei System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   bei Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.OnRun()
   bei Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.DoApplicationModel()
   bei Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.Run(String[] commandLine)
   bei Test.My.MyApplication.Main(String[] Args) in : Zeile83

I hope I have entered all the required information.
I have changed the AppId & TenantId from the M365.
I used Google to check whether the client secret is still valid (it is until mid-2025).
The emails should be sent automatically and without user interaction.
To keep it clearer in the forum, I have only inserted the code used from the class.
Many thanks in advance.
regards
Numbfumble

The ImpersonatedUserId has an Id property that must be set.

I set the ImpersonatedUserId with this .ImpersonatedUserId = New ImpersonatedUserId(ConnectingIdType.SmtpAddress, MailBoxAdress)}
Is this wrong?

I'm not familiar with it, but as said, the ImpersonatedUserId that you initialize there has an Id property that obviously has to be set, if you look at your stacktrace.
